# ASPNET MVC. How display a EnumDropDownListFor only with valid states

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I'm trying to display a select with some options. But only with valid options.

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.type)
```

this is my model

```
[Required]
public MyEnum type { get; set; }
```

this is the Enum

```
public enum MyEnum {
    ValueA = 0,
    ValueB = 1
}
```

But the rendered razor HTML shows a select with 3 values. one empty and two valid values.

```
<option selected="selected" value="68"></option>
<option value="0">ValueA</option>
<option value="1">ValueB</option>
```

And I dont understand why the "68" is rendered.

When the "empty" state is selected and submited it **DOES NOT** shows any validation error. It's quite unexpected.

How avoid the first one to be rendered?

Comment: Not able to duplicate this. Only 2 options are generated - `<option selected="selected" value="0">ValueA</option><option value="1">ValueB</option>`

Comment: Where is "68" value came from? Sounds that `Range` attribute or index change should be used on your enum model. I tried to reproduce this case but no "68" had present.

Comment: i suspect the empty value is added on the client side

Comment: There is code somewhere adding that 68 entry, its not magically appearing out of thin air.

Comment: I Will try to isolate it into a new project. And verify if it still occurs.